# How to use LLVMBuildGEP with LLVM C API

Tags: c, arrays, llvm, bison, clang++

I'm trying to use Bison and Flex to allow for an instruction that gets the value at an array index. For example, if the instruction was:

`(aref array 2)`

the instruction would load the value at index 2 of the array (3rd element).

I'm trying to compute the offset of the array by using LLVMBuildGEP(), but my LLVM instruction keeps accessing illegal memory and returning an invalid record error. I've looked at the [doxygen documentation](https://llvm.org/doxygen/group__LLVMCCoreInstructionBuilder.html#gaf392c575dd594d83894d3e71a520ffa4) but I'm not exactly sure what the arguments to the function mean. Right now I'm assuming the `Pointer` argument is the starting address of the array, the `Indices` argument is a pointer representation of the offset (I don't understand this), and the `NumIndices` argument is the number of elements you want to return, but I'm confused as to how this works and whether I'm using this right.

This is what I'm doing to try and retrieve the element in my bison file. `token_or_expr` can be evaluated to an integer, `LPAREN` and `RPAREN` are left and right parentheses, `aref` is the command, and `ID` is the array name. I'm getting the ID value using a map data structure that I'm absolutely sure works through various testing. The data structure returns an address that can be loaded from with an `LLVMBuildLoad`. `expr_no_return` is just a global variable that I set to 0 or 1 depending on whether or not I didn't pass a `LLVMValueRef` up the parse tree. Here's my implentation:

```
| LPAREN AREF ID token_or_expr RPAREN
{
  // IMPLEMENT
    LLVMValueRef loc = map_find($3);
    if(loc!=NULL){
        //$$ = LLVMBuildGEP(Builder,loc,$4,1,"element");

        LLVMTypeRef int32ptr = LLVMPointerType(LLVMInt32Type(),0);
        LLVMValueRef int2ptr = LLVMBuildIntToPtr(Builder,$4,int32ptr,"ptr");
        expr_no_return = 0;
        $$ = LLVMBuildGEP(Builder,loc,int2ptr,1,"element");
    }
    else{
        yyerror("ERROR: Undefined array.");
    }

    printf("AREF\n");
  //DONE
}
```

The compiler does throw out a warning that `int2ptr` is a `LLVMValueRef` and that it should be a `LLVMValueRef *`. I'm not sure how to go about this though.

Comment: I think your memory problem is that `LLVMBuildGEP` accepts multiple indices and thus expects a pointer to an `LLVMValueRef`. Just replace the function call with `LLVMBuildGEP(Builder,loc,&int2ptr,1,"element");`.

Comment: @user3684240. Just tried that. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Whenever I'm unsure about how to generate LLVM instructions in a specific situation, I look at what `clang` does. For a minimal example of what you're trying to do (`extern int a[4]; int b(long long n) { return a[n]; }`), `clang` generates a `getelementptr inbounds` on the array, a constant 0, and the index. Maybe it's worth trying to replicate that exact behaviour (`LLVMBuildInBoundsGEP`)?

Comment: @user3684240 Wow, I never thought do to that. That's really gonna speed up the progress on this project. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You're welcome! By the way, you can do this from within bash. I like to do `echo '(minimal c code)' | clang -xc - -o- -S -emit-llvm -O9` which directly prints LLVM IR.